# SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder post log4j Remediation

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

To Remediate log4j issue recently We made few changes to existing POM files.

We removed

```xml
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

And added

```xml
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
```

In the parent pom below is the slf4j version

```xml
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
<version>2.17.0</version>
```

Application is running fine but now we are getting warning message as

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Can someone help me in providing a solution to this please.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution mentioned officially in the slf4j website

https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder

I was using *logback* and *slf4j* (in *gradle*) , so the solution mentioned in the second paragraph was what worked for me.

Comment: To add the jar you just added something like `
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>`? log4j-slf4j2-impl is supposed to include that already...